# Using Speech Recognizer in android studio

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am using SpeechRecognizer intent on my android app, but I want to know if this feature is free, or I have to pay Google for using it.
Does it use this Goolge API: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/

This is the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "de-DE");
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "");

    try
    {
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing here you have what i found.

Comment: Google cloud API and Google Speech Recognizer (Android) are different.

The Google cloud API have to be online, use a subscription key etc, while Android Google Speech Recognizer is built in android library. (You are using this one)